# Cardano-Wallet register a wallet generated by Cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-address

I created a Wallet with Cardano-Cli following this instructions:

```
cardano-cli address key-gen   --verification-key-file vkf.payment --signing-key-file  skf.payment
```

After that I derived the address of that wallet

What I need to do now is to register this wallet on the Cardano-Wallet server, to feed the PA>B. But the Cardano-Wallet-Server requires a pub key hash or a nemonic phrase wallet recovery, to generate the `WALLET_ID`.

But the cardano-cli offers none of them.

Does anyone knows how to move from payment verification and signing keys to a public address or a mnemonic phrase useful to register my wallet on Cardano-Wallet-Server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone knows how to move from payment verification and signing
> keys to a public address or a mnemonic phrase useful to register my
> wallet on Cardano-Wallet-Server?

I think you're not able to make that kind of derivation since we are dealing with addr.xsk (from derivation path `root.xsk -> acct.xsk -> addr.xsk`). And wallet needs to know about root and acct keys.
You can however use [cardano-addresses](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses) to create all those keys and generate address with them, and then use `cardano-cli key convert-cardano-address-key` to convert them into format that is readable by `cardano-cli` if you wish:

1. Generate mnemonics

```
$ cardano-address recovery-phrase generate --size 24 > mnemonics.txt
```

Using these mnemonics you can already restore the wallet on cardano-wallet server.

2. Create root.xsk

```
$ cardano-address key from-recovery-phrase Shelley < mnemonics.txt > root.xsk
```

(BTW, at this point you can already figure out what will be wallet id)

```
$ cardano-address key walletid < root.xsk
```

3. Derive addr.xsk and stake.xsk

```
$ cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H/0/0 < root.xsk > addr.xsk  
$ cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H/2/0 < root.xsk > stake.xsk
```

4. Generate public/verification keys:

```
$ cardano-address key public --without-chain-code < addr.xsk > payment.vkey
$ cardano-address key public --without-chain-code < stake.xsk > stake.vkey
```

5. Generate wallet address:

```
$ cardano-address address payment --network-tag preprod < payment.vkey \
  | cardano-address address delegation $(cat stake.vkey) > payment.addr
```

addr.xsk -> `1852H/1815H/0H/0/0`, so this is going to be first address on the wallet, next in the sequence would be `1852H/1815H/0H/0/1` etc. (stake.xsk stays the same)

The address can be also generated with `cardano-cli`:

```
cardano-cli address build \
 --payment-verification-key-file payment.vkey \
 --stake-verification-key-file stake.vkey \
 --out-file paymentCli.addr \
 --testnet-magic 1 # preprod
```

You'll notice that `payment.addr` == `paymentCli.addr`.

6. Now, if you'd like to spend from the address also with `cardano-cli`:

Convert xsk:

```
$ cardano-cli key convert-cardano-address-key --shelley-payment-key --signing-key-file addr.xsk --out-file payment.skey
$ cardano-cli key convert-cardano-address-key --shelley-payment-key --signing-key-file stake.xsk --out-file stake.skey
```

Now, you can spend the address using cardano-cli (with payment.skey or stake.skey), e.g.:

```
$ cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat payment.addr) --testnet-magic 1

$ cardano-cli query protocol-parameters \
   --testnet-magic 1 \
   --out-file protocol.json

$ cardano-cli transaction build  \
    --babbage-era  \
    --testnet-magic 1 \
    --tx-in "3f546b8d958d65b9e0f93030ac4afdc95b92c0dfdadaad1a063bf7024ee0378d#0"  \
    --tx-out "addr_test1qzfdywms54mk9hclupc3yhu8yev6w92swndcaewvxx53ux0vwaztjw0fjsgfmvdqtq3tn4df0ja9tgvxmmapehnmjcxq8u7f98+1000000" \
     --change-address $(cat payment.addr) \
--protocol-params-file protocol.json  \
--out-file body.tx


$ cardano-cli transaction sign \
   --tx-body-file body.tx \
   --testnet-magic 2 \
   --signing-key-file payment.skey \
   --out-file signed.tx

$ cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file signed.tx --testnet-magic 1
```